# Android how to reset canvas/bitmap to capture a new image

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap, reset

I am working on an application in which i need to save table data as an image when the user clicks on a button. To do so I used the following code:

```
//save is the button to click
this.save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
        alert.setTitle("Save");
        alert.setMessage("Enter a file name");        
        final EditText input=new EditText(MyActivity.this);
        alert.setView(input);         
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                table.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
                Bitmap b=table.getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap combo=Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas=new Canvas(combo);
                canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0f, 175f, null);               
                OutputStream outStream = null;
                String value=input.getText().toString();
                File directory =new File(extStorageDirectory+"/Files/");
                if(!directory.mkdir())
                    directory.mkdir();
                File file = new File(directory, value);
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    combo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput("public.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE|Context.MODE_APPEND);
                    OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                                osw.write(value+"\n");                          
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();                                              
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                     
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                } catch (IOException e) {                       
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }
            }               
        });
```

This function saves an image with no problem but when i change my table and try to save another image it saves the first one. I think i need to reset the canvas or something like that so I tried the following after saving the file:

```
  canvas.restore();
```

But it doesn't work. But wheh i relaunch the application on the simulator i can save a new image. Can someone please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What type of object is table? You don't specify since it's part of your solution

Comment: @IcedDante it's a linear layout with Tablerow elements in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I just had to add

```
table.destroyDrawingCache();
```

just before catching exceptions.